# CI's from full model-averaged coefficients from model.avg (MuMIn package)

Tags: r, confidence-interval, information-theory

I am currently trying to get model-averaged estimates (and confidence intervals) for a GLMM I am running.

After obtaining a full set of candidate models using the `dredge()` function from the [MuMIn package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MuMIn/index.html) in R and selecting the 95% confidence set using:

```
avgmod.95 <- model.avg(all.mod, subset = cumsum(weight) <= .95)
```

'summary(avgmod.95)' gives me both the full and conditional parameter estimates (see below output of the reproducible example). The full estimates treat every parameter equally and averages them over all models (i.e., even those not containing the parameter, for which it gives the parameter a value of 0). These are the parameter estimates I'd like to report.

So far so good, but I'd also like to report confidence intervals. Running the function `confint(avgmod.95)` (as suggested in several papers) gives one confidence interval for each parameter (see reproducible example output below). However, these confidence intervals match the *conditional* parameter estimates much more closely than they do the *full* parameter estimates (which I am interested in).

My questions are:

- **Does the object generated with `model.avg()` only produce one set of confidence intervals, or does `confint()` give confidence intervals based on the conditional averages only?**
- **If the latter is the case, is there a way around this to obtain CI's for the full averages?**

Here's a reproducible example using the `mtcars` data:

```
require(lme4)
require(MuMIn)

# Fit the global model
global.model <- lmer(mpg ~ hp + drat*wt + (1|gear), data=mtcars)

# Set na.action to na.fail for dredge function to run
options(na.action="na.fail")

# Generate full model set
dr <- dredge(global.model)

# Generate model average values of 95% confidence set of models
avgmod.95 <- model.avg(dr, subset = cumsum(weight) <= .95)

# Get a summary of model averaged values (both full and conditional)
summary(avgmod.95)

# Get CI's for model parameter averages
confint(avgmod.95)
```

Now `summary(avgmod.95)` gives:

```
Call:
model.avg.model.selection(object = dr, subset = cumsum(weight) <= 
    0.95)

Component model call: 
lmer(formula = mpg ~ <4 unique rhs>, data = mtcars)

Component models: 
     df logLik   AICc delta weight
134   6 -73.31 161.97  0.00   0.76
1234  7 -73.53 165.73  3.75   0.12
13    5 -77.29 166.89  4.92   0.07
123   6 -75.89 167.14  5.16   0.06

Term codes: 
   drat      hp      wt drat:wt 
      1       2       3       4 

Model-averaged coefficients:  
(full average) 
             Estimate Std. Error Adjusted SE z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept) 11.208222  13.650695   14.120116   0.794   0.4273  
drat         6.851292   3.665723    3.784583   1.810   0.0702 .
wt           3.244549   4.455566    4.586870   0.707   0.4793  
drat:wt     -2.276614   1.341948    1.377762   1.652   0.0985 .
hp          -0.005121   0.011796    0.011856   0.432   0.6658  

(conditional average) 
             Estimate Std. Error Adjusted SE z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept) 11.208222  13.650695   14.120116   0.794  0.42733   
drat         6.851292   3.665723    3.784583   1.810  0.07025 . 
wt           3.244549   4.455566    4.586870   0.707  0.47935   
drat:wt     -2.594754   1.107692    1.156718   2.243  0.02488 * 
hp          -0.029439   0.009162    0.009600   3.066  0.00217 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Relative variable importance: 
                     drat wt   drat:wt hp  
Importance:          1.00 1.00 0.88    0.17
N containing models:    4    4    2       2
```

and `confint(avgmod.95)` gives:

```
                   2.5 %      97.5 %
(Intercept) -16.46669809 38.88314109
drat         -0.56635437 14.26893779
wt           -5.74555075 12.23464840
drat:wt      -4.86187937 -0.32762871
hp           -0.04825531 -0.01062219
```

Notice how the CI's confirm the conditional averages and not the full averages from the summary output.

Comment: Apologies. I am new to this site and didn't think of adding an example to this question. Hope the update helps!

Comment: Is the question still too off-topic, or can it be voted for reopening?

Comment: It depends on the intent of "way around this": are you looking for an `R` programming solution or for a statistical explanation, possibly with formulas or alternative approaches?

Comment: Use the argument full = TRUE i.e. confint(avgmod.95, full = T)